# I am creating a instance of my class and calling some functions. How can i release the object in a safe way

Tags: ios

I am creating a instance of my class here and calling some functions . When i try to rlease the object 
after my use i am getting this error `Thread 1: Program Recieved signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS` . How can i release the object in a safe way ....

```
   WebServicesiPhone *newsParser = [[WebServicesiPhone alloc] init];
   newsParser.splControlleriPhone = self;
   [newsParser getData:0:nil:0:0];
   [newsParser release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you could set up a property and release it in the dealloc method.

Second would be to autorelease that object. It will be released automatically once the object isn't retained amymore.

This would require you to retain the object where the call is comming from.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a dealloc method in WebServicesiPhone class, maybe you don't release recources of that class properly and that's causing your problems. Also make sure you set delegates to nil if you there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the property and Retain the Object.
as its retained now you have to dealloc the global instance.
and try using autorelease instead of release (it handle your obj validity).